# Convert Array of String column to multiple columns in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with following schema:

```
id         : int,
emp_details: Array(String)
```

Some sample data:

```
1, Array(empname=xxx,city=yyy,zip=12345)
2, Array(empname=bbb,city=bbb,zip=22345)
```

This data is there in a dataframe and I need to read `emp_details` from the array and assign it to new columns as below or if I can `split` this array to multiple columns with column names as `empname`,`city` and `zip`:

```
.withColumn("empname", xxx)
.withColumn("city", yyy)
.withColumn("zip", 12345)
```

Could you please guide how we can achieve this by using Spark (1.6) Scala.

Really appreciate your help...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `withColumn` and `split` to get the required data

```
df1.withColumn("empname", split($"emp_details" (0), "=")(1))
  .withColumn("city", split($"emp_details" (1), "=")(1))
  .withColumn("zip", split($"emp_details" (2), "=")(1))
```

Output:

```
+---+----------------------------------+-------+----+-----+
|id |emp_details                       |empname|city|zip  |
+---+----------------------------------+-------+----+-----+
|1  |[empname=xxx, city=yyy, zip=12345]|xxx    |yyy |12345|
|2  |[empname=bbb, city=bbb, zip=22345]|bbb    |bbb |22345|
+---+----------------------------------+-------+----+-----+
```

**UPDATE:**
If you don't have fixed sequence of data in `array` then you can use `UDF` to convert to `map` and use it as

```
val getColumnsUDF = udf((details: Seq[String]) => {
  val detailsMap = details.map(_.split("=")).map(x => (x(0), x(1))).toMap
  (detailsMap("empname"), detailsMap("city"),detailsMap("zip"))
})
```

Now use the udf

```
df1.withColumn("emp",getColumnsUDF($"emp_details"))
 .select($"id", $"emp._1".as("empname"), $"emp._2".as("city"), $"emp._3".as("zip"))
 .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+-------+----+---+
|id |empname|city|zip|
+---+-------+----+---+
|1  |xxx    |xxx |xxx|
|2  |bbb    |bbb |bbb|
+---+-------+----+---+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for quick response and I really appreciate the help. I have one more observation, if the values in an array always not in same order. For example, I may get one array as (city,zip,empname), other record I may get as (empname,city,zip). if these positions are changing dynamically, how can we read it? is there any option to read based on the name..

Comment: @Bab please check the updated answer. Now it wont matter how the data is in array.

Comment: Hi, For continuing above question, some times some key value pair may not come in the column(array of string) in a dataframe. How can we handle it dynamically. For example, in some records zip will be there or may not be there. Do we have any option to handle such situation. Thanks in Advance

Comment: That depends on you, You can return null or empty string by checking in the map.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you give example to return null if key is not present.

Comment: Thank you for the response and could you please provide me the example on how to return null or empty if the key is not present in the map.

Comment: @Bab sorry for the late response, just change the last line of udf to `(detailsMap.getOrElse("empname", null), detailsMap.getOrElse("city", null),detailsMap.getOrElse("zip", null))` should work to return null

Comment: @ShankarKoirala I have a similar situation however in my case Case a City or name could repeat several times. In such a case last string value is taken. How could I take it as array of elements ?

Comment: @carl In that case this still works I guess, please test it, while converting to map it overwrites for the previous same key.

Comment: Checked it, since it's Map old values get replaced instead of appending because they have same key.

Comment: If you want all in the list you can groupby its first value and make a list of multiple values before converting to map

Comment: @ShankarKoirala details.map(_.split("=")).map(x => (x(0), x(1))).groupBy(_._1).map { case (k,v) => (k,v.map(_._2))}.toMap did the trick for me. Thanks for the quick feedback.

Comment: @carl Great you did it.