# Creating Separate Spark dataframe from existing arraytype column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe as

[image]

with schema

```
StructType(structField("a",IntegerType,False),structField("b",IntegerType,False),structField("c",ArrayType(structType(structField("d",IntegerType,False),structField("e",IntegerType,False)))
```

I want to create a separate dataframe from column "c" which is of array type.

Desired output format is

[image]

Comment: look into the explode function :)

Comment: @GamingFelix Thanks for your help. Explode is not dynamically creating separate columns. Can you please help me with exact syntax  you are referring to, where you can have n number of columns in array.

Comment: Hi! does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609740/spark-dataframe-explode-list-column ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```scala
df.selectExpr("a", "b", "inline_outer(c)").show()
```

Comment: Wow. this is really useful.